# TikZ is colored despite having \setupcolors[state=stop]

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, context-mkiv

In the following MWE I get a red square, but I want it to be gray, as in the also provided LaTeX-document:

```
% ConTeXt MWE
\setupcolors[state=stop]
\usemodule[tikz]

\starttext
\tikz{\draw[color=red,fill] (0,0) rectangle (1,1)}
\stoptext
```

---

```
% LaTeX-document wich does what I want
\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\draw[color=red,fill] (0,0) rectangle (1,1)}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

After hitting official ConTeXt ML with this, it was told me, that it is an issue with TikZ, so I filed a bug over there: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/356/